# Scala - Drop records from DF1 if it has matching data with column from DF2

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two DF's(`railroadGreaterFile`, `railroadInputFile`).

I want to drop records from `railroadGreaterFile` if data in `MEMBER_NUM` column from `railroadGreaterFile` is matching the data in `MEMBER_NUM` column from `railroadInputFile`

Below is what i used:

```
val columnrailroadInputFile = railroadInputFile.withColumn("check", lit("check"))
val railroadGreaterNotInput = railroadGreaterFile
                               .join(columnrailroadInputFile, Seq("MEMBER_NUM"), "left")
                               .filter($"check".isNull)
                               .drop($"check")
```

Doing above, records are dropped, however i witnessed `railroadGreaterNotInput`'s schema is combination of my `DF1` and `DF2` so when I try to write the `railroadGreaterNotInput`'s data to file, it gives me below error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'GROUP_NUM' is ambiguous, could be: GROUP_NUM#508, GROUP_NUM#72
```

What should i be doing so that `railroadGreaterNotInput` would only contain fields from `railroadGreaterFile` DF?

Comment: You can rename the conflicting column names from railroadInputFile and just select railroadGreaterFile dataframe columns only after you join them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only select the `MEMBER_NUM` while joining

```
val columnrailroadInputFile = railroadInputFile.withColumn("check", lit("check"))
val railroadGreaterNotInput = railroadGreaterFile.join(
    columnrailroadInputFile.select("MEMBER_NUM", "check"), Seq("MEMBER_NUM"), "left")
   .filter($"check".isNull).drop($"check")
```

Or drop all the columns from `columnrailroadInputFile` as

```
columnrailroadInputFile.drop(columnrailroadInputFile.columns :_*)
```

but for this use join contition as

`columnrailroadInputFile("MEMBER_NUM") === railroadInputFile("MEMBER_NUM")`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm almost there, now i have first column as MEMBER_NUM followed by rest of the columns, is there a way i can swap the first and second columns in railroadGreaterNotInput?

Comment: I am not sure, what do you mean by swap the first and second column.

Comment: Schema of railroadInputFile is GROUP_NUM, MEMBER_NUM, ....
Schema of railroadGreaterFile is GROUP_NUM, MEMBER_NUM, ....
The final DF railroadGreaterNotInput's Schema shows MEMBER_NUM, GROUP_NUM....
I want the final DF to be in sync with my DF1 and DF2.

Comment: Do you wanna swap `GROUP_NUM` and `MEMBER_NUM`  and why do you wanna do that ?

Comment: You just need to use select("fields in order you want ")

Comment: Oh yeah, selecting the fields in the order i want will be my last take on this, was just curious if we can change the schema of my final DF altogether.

Comment: For that Either cast the each column as you require or create an schema that you want to apply and apply it by converting it to rdd.